# How the getContentResolver() method work?

Tags: android

How does it know which ContentProvider to use?
What if there are more than one contentProviders? How does it distinguish between them?

Comment: why don't you check the sources?

Comment: based on `android:authorities`, see manifest's `<provider>` tag documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The Android framework uses a concept called content providers to enable applications to share and use data across the platform.*** Typically, a provider is backed by a SQLite database where the underlying data is stored. ([sample source](http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/content-provider-example-1.html))

**Why would you need more than one?** Even complex data stores like contacts use a single ContentProvider.

***You can implement as many as you want***, as you can see from the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html). 
To register a content provider, you need to add its corresponding  tag in the Android Manifest.

In most cases, however, you won't need multiple content providers. 
One is usually enough, as it can handle multiple tables. 
You should only really need more than one if you want your app to provide public access to 2+ separate data entities.